# How to sum attributes of different objects?

Tags: javascript, object

JS noob here. How can I set a variable equal to the sum of the currentDays attributes of all three animal objects?

```
var foods = {

chicken: {
  'days': 1349.5,
  'deaths': 28.63,
  'currentDays': 1349.5,
  'currentDeaths': 28.63
  },

eggs: {
  'days': 456.25,
  'deaths': 1.733,
  'currentDays': 456.25,
  'currentDeaths': 1.733
  },

pork: {
  'days' :112.5,
  'deaths': .445,
  'currentDays': 112.5,
  'currentDeaths': .445
  },

};
```

Comment: It would help if you gave the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
var key, days = 0;

for (key in food) {
  if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(food, key) ) {
    days += foods[key].currentDays;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
for (var k in foods) {
    if (foods.hasOwnProperty(k))
        sum += foods[k].currentDays;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dWCAu/

Answer (score 0):

If you can count on a recent JavaScript engine, you can use the `reduce` method of the `Array` type:

```
Object.keys(foods).reduce(function (p,v,i,a) {
    return p + foods[v].currentDays;
}, 0);
```